# Copy to C Drive(Root) as administrator

Tags: asp.net

I want to copy a file in C root directory as an administrator, it is working fine for some path. The user I am using is having administrator rights but still I'm unable to copy.

My code is:

```
string strCmdText = string.Empty;
strCmdText = "copy /Y " + "\"" + fullpath + "\"" + " " + "\"" + _name.FullPath + "\\" + subject + ".msg" + "\"";
System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
startInfo.Verb = "runas";
startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
startInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
startInfo.Arguments = strCmdText;
startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
process.StartInfo = startInfo;
process.Start();
StreamWriter sw = process.StandardInput;
sw.WriteLine(strCmdText);
sw.Close();
process.WaitForExit();
string output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
process.Dispose();
process.Close();
```

I am getting the following error:
`You don't have appropriate permission to perform this operation.`

Comment: Try turning UAC off and see if it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taken from the comment.  This looks like UAC.  Try turning UAC off and if that works, then you know where to go next!

Answer (score 0):

Depending on you are running you web app locally or via network but normally to write to C drive you could add NETWORK SERVICE to target folder.

Answer (score 0):

Add This to your code:

```
startInfo.UserName = "Administrator";
startInfo.Password = "password";
```

Hope This Help.